# image with text in gridview android

Tags: android, image, gridview, text

I am developing application which havely based on images. I am displaying these images in GridView like this picture.

[image]

But i want to make this text and image in together like following picture.

[image]

One solution is that Create an image with text together and display in gridview but it does not look clean solution. Kindly guide me, If android provides some nice and clean solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A GridView extends from AdapterView. An AdapterView is a view whose children are determined by an Adapter. An AdapterView uses a the getView() method to retrieve currently shown items.

You can customize this getView() method to return any kind of View.

> e.g. a Relative Layout

This Relative Layout can contain an ImageView and a TextView

I hope this makes sense, if not comment below

Comment: Hey so I am trying this out, I am just having the issue where it shows one item in a listview format as oppose to a gridview... am I missing something here?